# Rewrite from url with querystring to folder

Tags: regex, url-rewriting, .net-core

I want rewrite url like this:

```
/files/b9f8d0b5e35248579953755b3677a59b.png?w=400&h=100&mode=crop
```

To:

```
/files/400/100/crop/b9f8d0b5e35248579953755b3677a59b.png
```

My rule like:

```
.AddRewrite(@"^files/(.*)?w=(\d+)&h=(\d+)&mode=(.*)$", "files/$2/$3/$4/$1", true)
```

But it's not working, how can i fix it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression starts with the `^` which makes the pattern only match when it starts with `files/`. Otherwise it looks pretty good. I've used `[^?]` as a character group that matches anything except the `?`, and a similar character group for `[^&]`.

```
AddRewrite(@"/files/([^?]+)\?w=(\d+)&h=(\d+)&mode=([^&]+)", "/files/$2/$3/$4/$1", true)
```

^ Tested on https://www.regexplanet.com/share/index.html?share=yyyyye98k3r

You might want to consider what will happen if the query parameter order changes.

Comment: Thanks, your regex pattern is right, but i found that rewrite module no handle querystring, so i need to find another solutions.